# Canada: work permit extension on old passport with an expired visa - Do I need a visa to come back from the US?

Tags: canada

I had a work permit that was valid until October 2019. There was a visa tied to the work permit which also had the same expiry date.

I have applied for the work permit extension and it is due to arrive in November 2019, which will be valid until March 2020. This work permit is on my old passport, which is due to expire in March 2020 as well. I have a new passport with me.

With this extended work permit, I am not sure if they issue a new visa (I am waiting for it to arrive). Reading from the online sources, it seems that I need to apply for a new visiting visa to travel outside Canada (I am an Indian citizen). A work permit doesn't authorize re-entry.

If I get back my work permit extension on time, will there be any problems to enter Canada if I travel to the US and come back? Do I need to apply for a new visa on my new passport? I know that a lot of countries have issues admitting someone with a passport due to expire in 6 months, and mine will expire in 2 months if I come back in January.

Comment: Canada has no six month rule, even for temporary visitors, but they may have a rule requiring the passport to be valid for the duration of your anticipated stay.  Such rules don't make sense for longer term residents, of course, so it may not apply to you.  The place to ask about that, however, is [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: I'm a little confused about the question. You say you have a new passport. If so, why do you worry about expiration? You can use a visa on an older passport with a new passport.

Comment: My visa on the old passport has expired, so I am currently waiting for the work permit extension. I am not sure if there will be a new visa with it, as they haven't asked for my passport yet.